# how can I write the admin panel in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-admin

I want to create a Django admin panel myself
[with this template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbLCu.png)

like this admin panel
How can I do this?

Comment: That's a very broad question. Please try yourself first and then come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is almost impossible. But you can change the layout of the admin panel with CSS. There are two packages that make the Django admin panel interesting.

1. https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-interface/
2. https://pypi.org/project/django-jet/